# Setting up navigational menu properly?

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I'm trying to get my Nav menu text to sit beside one another beside the logo like a real website would have.
I made a mockup of the side for reference linked below for viewing purposes.

I've been literally stressing myself out over this simply  mundane task, messing with margins, padding, floating, etc and no matter what I do to any of my elements either NOTHING happens or a whole bunch of shit will start flying all over the place and I can't even understand why.

[My mockup Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnM0L.jpg)

[How mine looks at present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6qsh.png)

```css
/*The Main Background*/
body {
    background-image: url(../img/background.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x
} 
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.HeaderBike{
    background-image: url(../img/HeaderBike.png);
    background-position: 260px 70px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 382px;
}

/* Nav Element */

/* Header Element */
.site-navigation li {
    height: 21px;
    width: 49px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    float: left;
}
.site-navigation a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
.site-navigation a:hover {
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

/* navmenu */
.navmenu{
    margin-top:15px;
    width: 490px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.search{
    float: left; 
}
.SearchGlass{
    margin: 30px 900px;
    float: left;
}
h2 {
    line-height: 0.8;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
    float:left; 
    text-align: left;
}
h1{
  
}

/* Class For Articles*/
.article{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 72px
}
.article img{
    width: 400px;
    height: 225px;
    margin-right: 1%
}
.article h1{
    float:left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22.5px;
}
.article p{
    float:left;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}
footer{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment3</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="Team Sky">
          <img src="img/TeamSkyLogo.png" alt="Team Sky Logo" style="float: left;">
          <nav class="site-navigation">
            <ul class="clearfix navmenu">
              <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">checkout</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">video</a></li>
              <li> 
                <form class="search">
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
                </form>  
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div id="HeaderBike" class="HeaderBike">
            <div>
              <h1>Team Sky</h1>
              <P>the road to yellow</P>   
            </div>                    
      </div>        
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display your list items inline block.

```css
/*The Main Background*/

body {
  background-image: url(../img/background.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.HeaderBike {
  background-image: url(../img/HeaderBike.png);
  background-position: 260px 70px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 382px;
}


/* Nav Element */


/* Header Element */

.site-navigation li {
  height: 21px;
  width: 49px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 11px;
  float: left;
}

.site-navigation a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.site-navigation a:hover {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}


/* navmenu */

.navmenu {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 490px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.navmenu li {
display: inline-block;
}

.search {
  float: left;
}

.SearchGlass {
  margin: 30px 900px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment3</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="Team Sky">
      <img src="img/TeamSkyLogo.png" alt="Team Sky Logo" style="float: left;">
      <nav class="site-navigation">
        <ul class="clearfix navmenu">
          <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">checkout</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">video</a></li>
          <li>
            <form class="search">
              <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="HeaderBike" class="HeaderBike">
        <div>
          <h1>Team Sky</h1>
          <P>the road to yellow</P>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you're not posting the needed code for the solution or you have some indentation erros in your html.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header class="Team Sky">
        <img src="img/TeamSkyLogo.png" alt="Team Sky Logo" style="float: left;">
        <nav class="site-navigation">
            <ul class="clearfix navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">checkout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">video</a></li>
                <li> 
                    <form class="search">
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search">
                    </form>  
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div id="HeaderBike" class="HeaderBike"> <--- open never closed
        <div>
        <h1>Team Sky</h1>
        <P>the road to yellow</P>   
        </div>
    </header> <--- this was after div that goes next                    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to split your header into 3 columns and then place your logo, navigation and search fields into each of those sections.

I have included an example below:

```css
.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}

.header__section {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.header__section:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header clearfix">
  <section class="header__section">
    Logo
  </section>
  <section class="header__section">
    Nav
  </section>
  <section class="header__section">
    Search
  </section>
</header>
```